# Reset UserDefaults when running UITests and restore on finish

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode-ui-testing

I've tried to reset and restore the `UserDefaults` when I start UITests and restore them when they finish respectively.
Here is a code that is use in AppDelegate:

```
func makeDefaultsBackup() {

    guard config.uiTesting else {return}

    if let domainName = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
        self.defaultsBackup = UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: domainName)

        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domainName)
    }
}

func applyDefaultsBackup() {

    guard config.uiTesting else { return }

    if let domainName = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,
        let persistentDomain = self.defaultsBackup {

        UserDefaults.standard.setPersistentDomain(persistentDomain, forName: domainName)
    }
}
```

But, when after UITests finished and I run App in basic mode all settings are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()` to get a dictionary of all stored keys and store this dictionary somewhere outside of the test function and then when you're done with the tests just loop over it and apply every value again

Comment: Do you have tried it? Yes i can, but it doesn't work too.